# Create buttons with negative border radius and align them in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I want to build a layout like this

[image]

Where the two external elements are buttons, while the inner one is a TextField.

How can I create a layout like this in Flutter?

My idea was to use absolute positions to align the left side of each element and to use elevation to handle overlapping but I'm not sure it's the best way and I don't know how to create the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `CustomPainter` class, with which you build the buttons. Then you use the `RawMaterialButton` and `CustomPaint` widget to use it in your application. To position and overlap the elements i would use the Stack widget.

[image]

Attached you see an example of your outer right button:

```dart
...
body: Center(
  child: RawMaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: ButtonShape(
        strokeColor: Colors.blue,
        strokeWidth: 1,
        paintingStyle: PaintingStyle.fill,
      ),
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text('+', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 36)),
        ),
        height: 50,
        width: 150,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
...


class ButtonShape extends CustomPainter {
  final Color strokeColor;
  final PaintingStyle paintingStyle;
  final double strokeWidth;

  ButtonShape({this.strokeColor = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 3, this.paintingStyle = PaintingStyle.stroke});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = strokeColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..style = paintingStyle;

    canvas.drawPath(shapePath(size.width, size.height), paint);
  }

  Path shapePath(double x, double y) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..cubicTo(x/2, 0, x/2, y, 0, y)
      ..cubicTo(x, y, x, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ButtonShape oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.strokeColor != strokeColor ||
        oldDelegate.paintingStyle != paintingStyle ||
        oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth;
  }
}
```

**Update:**
I've found another, more elegant, solution to solve this. Instead of using a `CustomPainter` you can use a `CustomClipper` with the `ClipPath` widget. Important is, that the `ClipPath` and the `color` of the button is outside the `RawMaterialButton`, only then, the ripple effect on tapping the button is the same shape as the button itself:

```dart
...
body Center(
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: ButtonClipper(),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 150,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('+', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 36)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
...

class ButtonClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.cubicTo(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height, 0, size.height);
    path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height, size.width, 0, 0, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(ButtonClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but when I tap the button the ripple is rectangular and outside of the shape. How can I change it so that it matches the shape of the button?

Comment: @matte_colo I used a new approach with ClipPath; see my updated answer