# How can I achieve the body part selection of a woman body using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to be able to click on different parts of woman body and be able to light-up (color) that particular body part.

I have tried to explore different pub packages like body_part_selector, human_body_selector but none of them is fitting my purpose of using a woman body for part selection as attached in the image. I should be able to click on any part of this image and it should light up. [Woman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaWqJ.png)

I have used the solution where I use this image as png, and wrap it with a gesture detector. Then I find out the location of selection using onTap and put a circle at that location in the stack. The problem with this solution is that it does not precisely light up that body part, instead it puts a circle on the image using a container. I need to improve this. Please suggest solutions.

```
class BodyImage extends StatefulWidget {
  String imageURL;
  BodyImage({required this.imageURL});

  @override
  _BodyImageState createState() => _BodyImageState();
}

class _BodyImageState extends State<BodyImage> {
  List<BodyPart> bodyParts = [
    BodyPart(name: 'Head', area: const Rect.fromLTWH(65, 0, 52, 52), color: Colors.red),
    BodyPart(name: 'Chest', area: const Rect.fromLTWH(55, 100, 72, 72), color: Colors.orange),
    BodyPart(name: 'Belly', area: const Rect.fromLTWH(55, 160, 72, 72), color: Colors.black),
    BodyPart(name: 'Arm', area: const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 180, 62, 62), color: Colors.blue),
    BodyPart(name: 'Leg', area: const Rect.fromLTWH(50, 300, 62, 62), color: Colors.green),
  ];

  BodyPart? selectedPart;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTapUp: (details) {
            setState(() {
              selectedPart = bodyParts.firstWhereOrNull((part) => part.area.contains(details.localPosition));
            });
            if (selectedPart != null) {
              Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                // AppNavigation.navigateTo(AppRoutes.bodyPain, arguments: ScreenArguments(bodyPart: selectedPart));
              });
            }
          },
          child: Image.asset(widget.imageURL),
        ),

        if (selectedPart != null)
          Positioned(
            left: selectedPart!.area.left,
            top: selectedPart!.area.top,
            child: Container(
              width: selectedPart!.area.width,
              height: selectedPart!.area.height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: selectedPart!.color,
              ),
              // child: Center(child: Text(selectedPart!.name)),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886168/how-do-i-make-a-specific-part-of-a-transparent-image-clickable/60893343#60893343 maybe it could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is quiet complex, you may have to play around with `CustomPaint` widget to get the shapes you're looking for instead of `Positioned` `Container`. for example:

```
      CustomPaint(
        painter: selectedPart != null ? LightArea(selectedPart!.area) : null,
        child: Image.asset(widget.imageURL),
      ),
```

I would implement the `LightArea` something like this:

```
class LightArea extends CustomPainter {
  LightArea(this.rect);
  final Rect rect;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LightArea oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.rect != rect;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Texv, thanks for your response. What do you mean by "to get the shapes you're looking for instead"

Comment: The part shapes in your png image are not circular or square. I was talking about those shapes where you need different curves, but maybe a small circle would look good and easier to implement?